# How to install jsdom in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, npm-install, jsdom

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. `react-native init myproject`.
2. `cd myproject`.
3. `npm install jsdom`.
4. In my **App.js**, I added `import jsdom from 'jsdom';`.
5. `react-native run-ios`.

**Expected Output:**
App starts on the React native landing page.

**Actual Output:**
Unable to resolve module `path` from `/Users/davidangulo/Desktop/mobile/myproject/node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js`: Module `path` does not exist in the Haste module map

According to their readme: (https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom)

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
```

That is how you initialize it but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: As far as I know, `jsdom` was made for nodeJS projects and not for `react-native` projects. Inside `jsdom/lib/api.js` on line 2, you'll see `const path = require('path')` and that module is not supported with react native.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey I had the same problem with jsdom and react-native, jsdom is made for node which would include path, fs and more, but react-native does not have all this.

For me [jsdom-jscore](https://github.com/iamcco/jsdom-jscore-rn) did the trick:

```
import { jsdom } from 'jsdom-jscore-rn'

// ...

const dom = jsdom(html)
```